# Error while upgrading from nexus 2 to 3 on isolated network

Tags: nexus, sonatype

when upgrading from nexus 2.14.1-01 to 3.1.0-04 I get an error

On nexus 3 log I see :

```
InternalServerException: HTTP 500 Internal server error.
```

On nexus 2 log I get :

```
healthCheck.rest.GAVResource - could not connect to sonatype server.
java.net.unknownHostException : rhc.sonatype.com: unkonwn error.
```

I'm on internal network and I have no way of connecting the internet so I cannot access this server, what can I do in order to solve this ?

Comment: Hi there, can you file an issue with the full stack trace of each exception over at: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS . This will help us diagnose the issue a bit better. Also can you give us the Nexus 2 and 3 complete logs?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, like I said I'm working in an isolated network(Working at IAF), so I have no way of taking any files outside of that network into the internet :(.
Is there anything specific that might help ?
Those are the only two errors the logs are writing.

Comment: Hmmm. That is a predicament :). See if you can generalize and get us more of the stack trace, if possible, but file an issue for sure. We will do what we can to help out!